# How to pass number as uint256 to Solidity function using web3.js

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I have a contract in Solidity :

```
function mint(uint256 quantity_) public payable {
        require(isPublicMintEnabled, 'minting not enabled');
        require(msg.value == quantity_ * mintPrice, 'wrong mint value');
        require(totalSupply + quantity_ <= maxSupply, 'sold out');
        require(walletMints[msg.sender] + quantity_ <= maxPerWallet, 'exceed max wallet');

        
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity_; i++) {
        uint256 newTokenId = totalSupply + 1;
        totalSupply++;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use the mint function using Web3.js like so:

```
  contract.methods.mint(amount).send({ from: state.connectedWallet })
```

The problem is that if I pass the `amount` as a JavaScript Number/String the contract fails.
I tried using BigNumber from web3.utils and `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint256',amount)`.

The contract is deployed on Harmony ONE pops testnet.

Comment: `amount` must be an integer, have you tried `parseInt`? What is the error message? Try `contract.methods.mint(amount).send({ from: state.connectedWallet, value: amoun })`

Comment: What error are u getting? is it the only function that causing error?

Comment: I am getting `Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM` I have tried with ParseInt and the value field in send.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I had to call the contract like so:

```
    const value = 1 * 1e18 // 1ONE
    const amount = 1
    contract.methods.mint(amount).send({ from: state.connectedWallet, value })
```